# When will Fantasy Baseball matchup ratings get populated?

Tags: yahoo-fantasy-sports

Yahoo! Fantasy Baseball provides an analysis of player matchup favorability under the heading of "Matchup Ratings". The UI navigation element is still available, but the content has yet to be provided this season (2015).

When will this content return?

[image: Matchup Ratings aren't populated]

Answer (score 1):

From [Yahoo's User Voice thread on this subject](https://yahoo.uservoice.com/forums/255844-fantasy-sports-community-forum/suggestions/7598886-does-anyone-know-why-my-matchup-rating-function-is):

**Jake (Community Support Manager, Yahoo) commented  ·  May 20, 2015 15:55**

> Hey guys,
>
> I'm sorry to disappoint, but I'm not getting any updates besides
>   'they're still coming'.
>
> I share in this frustration, I too love and regularly use this feature
>   when analyzing my roster moves. I particularly like the way it's been
>   integrated into the 'Opponents' tab, and I've been pushing regularly
>   for more clarification on when these will be available.
>
> But, every answer I get back is 'TBD', so regardless of the reasons
>   why, they're not ready yet, and you have my apologies for the
>   continued inconvenience....and my lack of a reliable answer.
>
> I'll continue to revisit this post until we have matchup ratings live.
>   Know that I truly appreciate your continued patience (with me at
>   least). ;)
>
> For those of you who may have feedback, know that this isn't the best
>   place to lodge it. There are forums for each game we offer, and you
>   can leave feedback directly with the product team by way of these
>   forums. The below link goes to our help article which details the link
>   to each forum:
>
> http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SLN6580&locale=en_US&y=PROD_SPORTS_FAN_BASE

and

**Jake (Community Support Manager, Yahoo) commented  ·  May 06, 2015 14:49**

> Hi All,
>
> I'm still getting the thumbs up regarding sometime this week, but in
>   all honesty, it may not be exactly on time. I know that we're close,
>   but this unfortunately isn't a matter of us just flipping a switch to
>   get these live; there are 3rd party requirements that we don't control
>   related to the delays.
>
> I'll continue to update as I get more information. If I hear that it's
>   being pushed out, or get specifics on the launch date for these, I'll
>   post it here before anywhere else ;)